# Calling server side event in asp.net from java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

Surely will be marked as duplicate one but after tons of question and example i couldn't solve my problem. 

**What i want?**
Calling server side event handler in asp.net from client side java script it is not going on server side. I checked it by setting breakpoint, the page flicks but server side method is not called.

My click event on code behind is

```
  protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // my code
  }
```

aspx file

```
   <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="btn"
      OnClientClick="DoPost()" Text="Save" />
```

Javascript method is

```
   function DoPost() {
        function DoPost() {
        var chk = document.getElementById('<%= chkstatus.ClientID %>');
        if (chk.checked)
            __doPostBack('<%= btninsert.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');
        return true;
        //return false;
    } 
    }
```

I also tried this 
        `__doPostBack('btninsert', 'OnClick');` and `__doPostBack('btninsert', '');` and `$('btnSubmit').trigger('click');` with no success.

**What am i doing wrong?**

**Edit:** If i uses `OnClick` event then it is going in the server side event irrespective of the `if condition` in the `DoPost` method.

Comment: Where are you attaching btninsert_Click event handler to your button?

Comment: @Deyneka Do i need to attach it? how?

Comment: You use OnClientClick event for client attaching. Use OnClick for server event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahh it was simple. Thanks to all answers.
**Solution**:
Use `OnClick` attribute for server side event and `OnClientclick` for client event for validation.
`OnClientClick` javascript method will return `true` and `false` which decides whether serverside onclick event will fire or not.
Code will be somthing like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function DoPost() {
        var chk = document.getElementById('<%= chkstatus.ClientID %>');
        if (chk.checked) {
            var c = confirm("are you sure?");
            if (c == true) {
                return true;
            } else
            { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    } 
</script>
```

And the Button tag

```
<asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="btn"
   OnClientClick="return DoPost();" OnClick="btninsert_Click" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: yes, __doPostBack is not neccessary in this case, but it still works in your case. __doPostBack is a general solution, let's say you want to trigger another event inside your DoPost() if some conditions are met, you can call __doPostBack(anotherControl,event). That's what is suggested in my answer

Comment: the thing is you forgot to return false (in your question) to prevent postback of the current control.

Comment: yes @KhanhTo __doPostBack is general but it didnt posted back to the server. May be i missed something that is required for __doPostBack to fire.

Answer (score 4):

it can work!!

if you call __doPostBack('btninsert', ''), add below to Page_Load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "btninsert" ) {
        btninsert_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the click event sender is casted to the `Button` object to get `CommanArgument`. However, this throws unable to cast exception. How can i solve this?

Comment: @ibubi: You can also call another method instead of an event. If you supply the second parameter of the __doPostBack, you can get the value from Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]. An example where this will help is if you want to do something with an object on a list view. i.e. delete an item from a collection then bind it to the list view to get an updated list on the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btninsert_Click" OnClientClick="DoPost()" Text="Save" />
```

Add `OnClick="btninsert_Click"`, because without this information, asp.net has no way know which event handler to run for the "Click" event. In case you want to control whether to post back by client side script. You can do something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btninsert_Click" OnClientClick="return DoPost()" Text="Save" />

function DoPost() {
        __doPostBack('<%= btninsert.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');
        return true;
      //return false;
    }
```

Note the `OnClientClick="return DoPost()"`

Comment: did as you told. it always goes on server side. i have a condition on postback as in my edited code. thats why i was not defining Onclick event.

Comment: in your updated function, you did not return false. You must return false in case you don't want a post back

Comment: @syed mohsin: In your case, as I understand. The postback is possible when the checkbox is checked, else no postback. You can try replacing "return true" with "return false". My code is just an example, you should return true or false based on your case

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="btn"
      OnClientClick="return DoPost();" Text="Save" />
```

modify your line like this

Comment: did it. nothing happened. same

Comment: yup. i attached the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ajax, by using Webmethod. I used this in my project and it works fine! You may see the question, solutions and code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/416748/How-to-Call-WebMethod-of-Csharp-from-JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP link button instead of ASP BUTTON. Button control is not called from javascript because it type is submit while link button type is button.

For example i have added two asp control

```
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtest" runat="server" Text="Link Button"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnbutton" Text="Button" />
```

and execute the page
When we view the source of running page its look like this

```
        <a id="lbtest" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbtest','')">Link Button</a>
        <input type="submit" name="btnbutton" value="Button" id="btnbutton" />
```