# Trying to trigger a button.click() event in ASP.NET from JavaScript. Event won't trigger

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, click

I have a C# ASP.NET application with some JavaScript components. In particular, there is a JavaScript popup where the user can enter some details and then press ok (JavaScript button) to submit the data. This will then call a JavaScript function Ok() which will process the data and close the popup.

I want the Ok() function to also call click() on an ASP button on the server side, but the event won't fire even though the correct element is captured at runtime.

The code extract in question:

```
function Ok() {

var btn = document.getElementById("aspBtn");
btn.click();

[ some extra processing ]

}
```

What baffles me the most is that this exact click() event on this exact button is called in another part of the code successfully. Please advise.

EDIT: I couldn't fix this in a satisfactory manner so instead will use a server button. Not ideal from a UI point of view, but it will have to do.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use the server side button directly..?

Comment: use document.getElementById('<%# aspbutn.ClientId%>')

Comment: did you look on browser's console window for some exception ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710768/calling-server-side-event-in-asp-net-from-java-script

Comment: Why can't I use server side button directly: it is a legacy web app and I need to add things around the existing code. In this case, I need to add the data entered in the popup window into a database table when the ok button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

the asp button id changes when it runs on the browser 
try this

```
document.getElementById('<%=aspBtn.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: With this, I get:
Uncatcht type error: Cannot call method 'click' of null

Comment: try adding this

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger event.

```
  function Ok() {

    document.getElementById('<%# aspbutn.ClientId%>').trigger("click");

    [ some extra processing ]

    }
```

For further information, see the below link.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

```
function Ok() {

document.FormName.btn.click();

[ some extra processing ]

}
```