# Stopping callback of DevExpress button

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, devexpress, visual-studio-2005

I have integrated jquery validation engine on my asp.net (vb) page. The validation works fine. When button is clicked, it shows jquery validation errors but at the same time function in code behind is also called.
I want to stop that call to function at code behind if there is jquery validation error on the page.

The code of button is :

```
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="btnSave"
EnableClientSideAPI="True"  Text="Save" ValidationGroup="Update" ClientEnabled ="true" 
ToolTip="Save Information">

</dxe:ASPxButton>
```

I saw client side event handler while googling this issue but I am not getting how to implement it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks..
Anjum

Comment: have u checked this [tutorial](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9448)

Comment: Yes, I went through it but couldn't found solution to my problem

Comment: or u can call server side event from client side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16729456/3184380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check Form is valid or not on form Submit or click of btnSave. If not valid then return false. May I know which jquery validation plugin you are using.

you need to check like this on btnSave click

```
$('btnSave').click(function(){

  if(!$('form#login').validate()) return false;

})
```

Change the id of form and save button

try this...

```
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    if(!$('form#login').validate()) return false;
}" />
```

change the form ID

Or If it is not working then You can use it

```
 <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
        if(!$('form#login').validationEngine('validate'))  e.processOnServer = false;;
    }" />
```

Comment: Jquery validation engine : https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: Actually i want it to be done through "client side event handler" of devExpress button

Comment: Yes but using `e.processOnServer = false`

Comment: `<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    if ( jQuery('#form1').validationEngine('validate') == false){
       e.processOnServer = false;
    }
}"/>`

Comment: may be.. It may be the way of DEVexpress... I am just giving answer as jquery help

Comment: Accepted your answer :-)