# Making One checkbox mandatory out of four checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have four checkbox, I want that a user should alteast check one checkbox for submitting the form. Please see my checkbox html for your reference.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCropLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check" onclick="javascript:enableTextBox();" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkInvestmentLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
```

Let me know if I can do this in jquery on button click event. Also see my button html code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="button-form" Width="100" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  CausesValidation="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this on button click.

javascript code:

```
function validateChecked() {
    var cnt = $('.check').is(':checked').length;
    if (cnt > 0) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
};
```

html code:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="clcheck" value="One" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="clcheck" value="Two" />
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="validateChecked();" />
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: jQuery's `.is` actually returns a boolean. You'll want to use `.filter` instead, or simply select `$('.check:checked')` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the correct, i was a bit hurried in my reply. pardon me.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
function enableTextBox(){
 if($(".check:checked").length == 0)
 {
   alert('please check atleast one checkbox');
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

And use it like `onclick="return javascript:enableTextBox();"`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of checkbox checked inside function `validate_checkbox`

```
$(function(){
  validate_checkbox = function(){
    if($('.check:checked').length==0)
    {
                // validation failed
      alert('please check atleast one checkbox');
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      // validation success
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncXfp/7/)

Comment: what u mean to say is correct, but I already have some other events fired on button click event "btnSubmit_Click" on code behind.

Comment: ok, then you can put this if / else part in "btnSubmit_Click" that you are already using.

Comment: can u describe it please ??

Comment: "I already have some other events fired on button click event "btnSubmit_Click" on code behind.", does this mean you have "btnSubmit_Click" function already there in your code?

Comment: yes i have that in code behind: protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked && txt_custId.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            div_errorMsg.InnerText = "Please enter your Customer Id.";
            return;
        }
}

Comment: Then I think, in the else part of my answer you should call this "protected void btnSubmit_Click(.." method and call javascript function btnSubmit_Click  on button click

Comment: how to call that method ? else { 
btnSubmit_Click();
}
like this, but i think it won't work

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710768/calling-server-side-event-in-asp-net-from-java-script here they have used OnClientClick and onClick (check in answer part)

Comment: thanks for the link, but your validation is not working exactly. It gives me validation error even after checking a single checkbox.

Comment: have you changed if condition as I updated in answer. please check for if($('.check:checked').length==0).

Comment: what needs to be changed ? I am using .check class for using the validation. should I replace that with id's # ?

Comment: no ...I have renamed function to 'validate_checkbox' in my answer. Call this same code for OnClientClick="return validate_checkbox();"of submit button and keep OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" as it is.

Comment: done with that also, but still its giving me the validation on check of checkbox

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxYUE/1/
i think asp controls are not displaying in js fiddle

Comment: ohhk, going for lunch.will try after a break. u can also join :) thanks for ur patience

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to force the user to select a specific check box , this would do 
`<input required type="checkbox" name="chk_mand">`

Comment: I have a asp control for checkbox